# Cant assign widget from map of widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-widget

I am developing a flutter project I have map which I can navigate among screens

but I can't use it I get this error

> `The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'`
> this is an error screenshot [image]

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your `Object` to `Widget`:

```
body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget
```

Comment: You're goddamn right, done